# Generic function template that returns a container of size one less than size of input container

Tags: c++

I would like to implement a function that takes a random access container of N>=1 elements and returns another random access container of N-1 elements. I would like the function to work with std::array, std::vector, std::valarray, and be extensible to other non-standard random access containers. If it could work with plain C arrays, that would be a bonus but not a requirement.

The application is uni-variate Bernstein polynomial derivative wherein the polynomial coefficients are stored in a random access container (typically pretty small, i.e., N<=10). Here is an example of how it might look:

```
template <class InputContainer, class OutputContainer /* deduced from InputContainer? */>
OutputContainer compute_derivative(const InputContainer &c)
{
   // Create and return an OutputContainer by iterating over elements of c
}
```

Further, `InputContainer::value_type` could be `float`, `double`, `std::complex<float>`, `std::complex<double>`, or possibly even `std::array` or `std::vector`. These elements represent the coefficients of the Bernstein polynomial and determine whether the the polynomial is a scalar function, a planar curve (coefficient with 2 elements), or a spatial curve (coefficient with 3 elements), or higher order.

Are there any examples people of know that handle this type of application generically for the containers I've mentioned and types held inside the container? I'd like to implement the algorithm once and have it work for all the possible permutations of container type and coefficient type, but I realize this might not possible.

An example implementation that assumes `std::vector<double>`:

```
std::vector<double> compute_derivative_coefficients(const std::vector<double>& c) {
  const auto N = c.size();
  std::vector<double> c_d;  // empty
  if (N > 1) {              // 0 or 1 element vectors both return an empty vector
    c_d.reserve(N - 1)
    for (std::size_t k = 0; k < N - 1; ++k) {
      c_d[k] = (N - 1) * (c[k + 1] - c[k]);
    }
  }
  return c_d;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to copy the array into a new N-1 sized array or create a "view" on the existing container?  For less than 10 coefficients copying should be reasonable.  What have you tried?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want to write this in a way that it accepts a `vector` and returns a `deque`, you might want to clarify that. In any case, removing an element from a container seems trivial, so why bother writing a function for that. Even if, writing such a function seems trivial as well. Can you do it for just one kind of container and without all the template stuff?

Comment: The algorithm is not a simple copy. If a std::array<double, 3> was the input container, the output result would be std::array<double, 2>. If all I had to support was std::array, I can see how to implement, but I also want a std::vector to work ideally without having to rei-mplement in a specialization. Description of the Bernstein polynomial can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2164549

Comment: I've edited my example to show a possible implementation that uses std::vector. I'd like to understand how/if I can make this more generic to accommodate std::array, std::valarray, or even plain C arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to unpack here.

First. Deducing the output container type is not as trivial as it sounds as for instance an `array<T,N>` must deduce to a type `array<T,(N-1)>` while `vector<T>` must return a `vector<T>` (the same as the input type). So I belive you would have to manually specify deduction rules for all container types that vary from some default. E.g.:

```
template <typename Container>
struct Otp {
  typedef Container Type;
};

template <typename T, ::std::size_t N>
struct Otp<::std::array<T,N>> {
  typedef ::std::array<T,(N-1)> Type;
};
```

And so on. (Disclaimer this is to show the idea, I didn't run this, nor does this claim to consider all possible requirements.)

Second, the actual implementation of the function. If you want it to work with any container type, you will in some form or other have to use iterator pairs. Specifically `::std::begin(c)` and `::std::end(c)` because member functions vary for different types and C-style arrays don't have any.

The trouble is now that constructing a `vector<T>` and an `array<T,(N-1)>` are two fundamentally different things because the array immediately initialises its members and has size `N-1` while the vector starts out with size `0` (and capacity `0`).

So it stands to reason that you want to directly initialise the container with the content that goes into it.

You would need an initialisation function of the sort `OutputContainer oc = {begin,end-1};`. Unfortunately, to my knowledge, no such operation exists for [list-initialised](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) types such as `T[]` or `array`.

---

So, I suppose your best bet is to distinguish between types that need list initialisation and hope that all these types are default constructible and immediately have their final size. You can then implement two versions of your general-purpose function. One that just default initialises the return value container and then fills it with content. Perhaps you can get away with an `if constexpr` over the distance between their `end` and `begin` iterators, there. The second version is for types that understand iterator pairs such as `vector`.

All in all, this is probably not trivial and has many pitfalls. I expect one would learn a lot about containers while properly implementing such a general function, but I am fairly certain that it would be much easier to just implement it for the handfull of types that you expect it to be used for.